# Why crawling s3 from databricks runs out of memory?

Tags: amazon-s3, pyspark, databricks

I have got an s3 bucket mounted to databricks like this:

```
dbutils.fs.mount(f"s3a://{bucket}", "/mnt/data")
```

Under the bucket, there are folders containing files and I just list those out like this:

```
from pathlib import Path
folder_path = Path(f'/dbfs/mnt/data/{folder_name}')
file_names = [p.name for p in folder_path.glob('*')]
print(f"# of files = {len(file_names)}")
```

There is a folder with a little over 2 million files and listing it out gobbles up several GB of memory and the driver crashes eventually (single node cluster with 32 GB memory). Here's how the ganglia UI looks:

[image]

I tried listing the files using `dbutils.fs.ls` instead of `pathlib` and it takes even longer to run and runs out of memory like the above.

This leads me to suspect that the databricks implementation of crawling s3 is very poorly implemented. Or am I doing something obviously wrong here? Note that I can't control the structure of the folder under the bucket, so a folder could have 100 million files under it without the files split into sub folders.

Comment: try os.scan_dir

Answer (score 0):

for a large number of files in S3 you'll want to use the boto3 API that supports pagination. This is considered best practice unless it can be guaranteed that the object listing is restricted

[Boto3 Docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html)

Comment: The Databricks cluster is authenticated to s3 using an instance profile. Any pointers on how to configure boto3 to use the instance profile to connect to s3?